# C Program to get contact from user and add it to a file

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I wrote this code to get input from user and add it to a file. When I ran this code on an online compiler, I got a message informing me that there is a problem with the call to the `scanf` function. I'm not able to understand this problem. Would you please help me to solve this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    char firstName   [20];
    char lastName    [20];
    int  phoneNumber [10];
    char email       [50];
    char address     [100];
    int  dayOfBirth  [2];
    int  monthOfBirth[2];
    int  yearOfBirth [4];
} contact;

void addcontact() {
    FILE *p,*q;
    p = fopen("p.txt", "r+");
    printf(" please enter the first name");
    scanf(" %s", &contact.firstName);
    printf(" next, enter the last name");
    scanf(" %s", &contact.lastName);
    printf(" enter the phone number");
    scanf(" %d", &contact.phoneNumber);
    printf(" enter the email");
    scanf(" %s", &contact.email);
    printf(" enter the address");
    scanf(" %s", &contact.address);
    printf(" enter the day , month and year of birth");
    scanf(" %d %d %d", &contact.dayOfBirth, &contact.monthOfBirth, &contact.yearOfBirth);
    q = fclose(p);
}
```

I even tried to remove the `&`.

PS: The project is a phone book.

Comment: When we input strings using `scanf` with `%s`, we do not use `&`. You can learn more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Did you really get the message "There is a problem with scanf"? Or did you actually get a way more specific error?

Comment: i didn't get it specified actually but when i removed the & as you mentioned and i added contact input; as mentioned in another answer it worked without errors but i got this message that i couldn't under /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function _start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status stand

Comment: i am using an online compiler by the way

Comment: it' a part of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read the input without declaring the variable for structure.

```
typedef struct{
  char firstName [20];
  char lastName[20];
  int phoneNumber[10];
  char email[50];
  char address[100];
  int dayOfBirth[2];
  int monthOfBirth[2];
  int yearOfBirth [4];
}contact;

scanf(" %s",&contact.firstName);
```

`contact` is datatype.
You need to declare the variable of type `contact`.

**Example:**

```
contact input;
scanf(" %s", input.firstName);
```

Comment: everything is ok except this message which appeared 

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @yasmine You need to add a main function in your program.